# How to change color of place holder in struts2.for example placeholder="year" .I want to change the font color of year in grey color

Tags: struts2

How to change color of place holder in struts2.for example placeholder="year" .I want to change the font color of year in grey color. If I try to change the color, the whole list color is changed. Just I want to change the color of  “year” into grey color.

```
<s:select   list="experienceYear" name="toYear" id="toYear" headerKey="0" 
    headerValue="Year" cssStyle="height:32px; width:14%; "   cssClass="profile-input"    placeholder="Year"/>
```

Comment: don't 4get to give me an upvote......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

**HTML**:

```
<select id="toYear">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Year...</option>
    <option value="1">2011</option>
    <option value="2">2013</option>
    <option value="2">2014</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#toYear option { color: black; }
.empty { color: gray; }
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$("#toYear").change(function () {
if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
else $(this).removeClass("empty")
});
$("#toYear").change();
```

**Working example**: **http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/1466/**